# Problems with continue to prompt for a valid choice within a case for Java

Tags: java

Hello I am having a hard to getting my code to work I have most of it working but when it comes to the menu it falls apart. All I am trying to do is:

Implement the printMenu() method. printMenu() has a ShoppingCart parameter, and outputs a menu of options to manipulate the shopping cart. Each option is represented by a single character. Build and output the menu within the method.

If an invalid character is entered, continue to prompt for a valid choice. Hint: Implement Quit before implementing other options. Call printMenu() in the main() method. Continue to execute the menu until the user enters q to Quit.

I have the menu part already completed but it continuously loops. The code is below for the menu section:
            **ItemToPurchase**
           public class ItemToPurchase {

```
private String itemName;
private int itemPrice;
private int itemQuantity;
private String itemDescription;
public ItemToPurchase(){
   this.itemName = "none";
   this.itemPrice = 0;
   this.itemQuantity = 0;
   this.itemDescription = "none";
```

}

```
public ItemToPurchase(String itemName, int itemPrice, int itemQuantity, String 
itemDescription)
{
   this.itemName = itemName;
   this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
   this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
   this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
}


public String getName(){
   return itemName;
}

public void setName(String itemName){
   this.itemName = itemName;
}

public int getPrice(){
   return itemPrice;
}

public void setPrice(int itemPrice){
   this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
 }

 public int getQuantity(){
   return itemQuantity;
 }

 public void setQuantity(int itemQuantity){
   this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
 }

 public String getDescription(){
   return itemDescription;
}

public void setDescription( String itemDescription){
   this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
}


  public void printItemCost(){
    int subtotal = itemQuantity * itemPrice;
    System.out.print(itemName+" "+itemQuantity+" @ $"+itemPrice+" = 
   $"+subtotal);
    System.out.println("");
}

  // Prints the item name
// and description
public void printItemDescription(){
   System.out.println(this.itemName + ": "+ this.itemDescription);
      }



     }


      **ShoppingCart**
     import java.util.ArrayList;
 public class ShoppingCart {
 private String customerName;
 private String currentDate;
 private ArrayList<ItemToPurchase> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();

 public ShoppingCart(){
    customerName = "none";
    currentDate = "1 January, 2016";
    //cartItemToPurchases = new ArrayList<ItemToPurchase>();
 }

 public ShoppingCart(String customerName, String currentDate){
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.currentDate = currentDate;
    //cartItemToPurchases = new ArrayList<ItemToPurchase>();
 }

 public String getCustomerName(){
    return customerName;
 }

 public String getDate(){
    return currentDate;
 }
public void setCustomerName(String customerName){
this.customerName = customerName;
}

public void setDate(String currentDate){
this.currentDate = currentDate;
}

public void addItem(ItemToPurchase itemToPurchaseToPurchase){
    if(cartItems != null){
        cartItems.add(itemToPurchaseToPurchase);
    }
}

public void removeItem(String itemName){
    if(cartItems != null){
    for(ItemToPurchase itemToPurchase : cartItems){
    if(itemToPurchase.getName().equals(itemName)){
    cartItems.remove(itemToPurchase);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.");
    }
 }

 public void modifyItem(ItemToPurchase itemToPurchaseToPurchase){
    boolean itemFound = false;
    if(cartItems != null){
    for(ItemToPurchase item : cartItems){
    if(item.getName().equals(itemToPurchaseToPurchase.getName())){
         itemFound = true;

         if(!itemToPurchaseToPurchase.getDescription().equals("none")){
             item.setDescription(itemToPurchaseToPurchase.getDescription());
  }
        if(itemToPurchaseToPurchase.getQuantity() != 0){
           item.setQuantity(itemToPurchaseToPurchase.getQuantity());
                }
        if(itemToPurchaseToPurchase.getPrice() != 0){
           item.setPrice(itemToPurchaseToPurchase.getPrice());
                }
            }
        }
        if(itemFound != true){
            System.out.println("Item not found in cart. Nothing modified.");
        }
    }
   }

  public int getNumItemsInCart(){
    int totalQuantity = 0;
    if(cartItems != null){
    for(ItemToPurchase itemToPurchase : cartItems){
        totalQuantity += itemToPurchase.getQuantity();
        }
    }
    return totalQuantity;
  }

 public int getCostOfCart(){
    int totalCostOfCart = 0;
    if(cartItems != null){
     for(ItemToPurchase itemToPurchase : cartItems){
         totalCostOfCart += (itemToPurchase.getQuantity()* 
itemToPurchase.getPrice());
        }
    }
    return totalCostOfCart;
 }

 public void printTotal(){
    if(cartItems == null || cartItems.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY.");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(customerName+"\'s"+" Shopping Cart - "+currentDate);
    System.out.println("Number of Items: "+getNumItemsInCart());
    System.out.println();              
    for(ItemToPurchase itemToPurchase : cartItems){
        itemToPurchase.printItemCost();        
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total: $"+getCostOfCart());
}

public void printDescriptions(){
    if(cartItems == null || cartItems.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY.");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(customerName+"\'s"+" Shopping Cart - "+currentDate);
    System.out.println("\nItem Descriptions");
    for(ItemToPurchase itemToPurchase : cartItems){
        itemToPurchase.printItemDescription();
    }
 }


 }
      **ShoppingCartManager**
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;
      public class ShoppingCartManager{
       private static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(System.in));
      // Prints a menu of options
    public static void printMenu(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
               throws IOException
        {
       char choice = ' ';
         while (true)
    {
       System.out.println("\nMENU");
       System.out.println("a - Add item to cart");
       System.out.println("d - Remove item from cart");
       System.out.println("c - Change item quantity");
       System.out.println("i - Output items' descriptions");
       System.out.println("o - Output shopping cart");
       System.out.println("q - Quit");
       System.out.println("");
       System.out.println("Choose an option:");
       choice = br.readLine().charAt(0);

       if (!((choice == 'a') || (choice == 'd') ||
               (choice == 'c') || (choice == 'i')
               || (choice == 'o')|| (choice == 'q')))
       {
          System.out.println("Choose an option:");
       choice = br.readLine().charAt(0); 
       continue;
       }
       else
       {
           switch (choice)
           {

           case 'a':
               System.out.println("ADD ITEM TO CART");
               System.out.println("Enter the item name:");
               String itemName = br.readLine();
               System.out.println("Enter the item description:");
               String itemDesc = br.readLine();
               System.out.println("Enter the item price:");
               int itemPrice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
               System.out.println("Enter the item quantity:");
               int itemQty = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
               ItemToPurchase it = new ItemToPurchase(itemName,
                       itemPrice, itemQty, itemDesc);

               shoppingCart.addItem(it);


               break;
           // Remove item
           case 'd':
               System.out.println("REMOVE ITEM FROM CART");
               System.out.println("Enter name of item to remove:");
               itemName = br.readLine();

               shoppingCart.removeItem(itemName);
               break;
           // Change item quantity
           case 'c':


               System.out.println("CHANGE ITEM QUANTITY");
               System.out.println("Enter item name:");
               itemName = br.readLine();
               System.out.println("Enter the new quantity:");
               itemQty = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
               ItemToPurchase item = new ItemToPurchase(itemName, 0, itemQty, 
                    "none");
               item.setName(itemName);
               item.setQuantity(itemQty);
               shoppingCart.modifyItem(item);

               break;
           // Output items' descriptions
           case 'i':
               System.out.println("OUTPUT ITEMS' DESCRIPTIONS");
               shoppingCart.printDescriptions();
               break;
           // Output shopping cart
           case 'o':
               System.out.println("OUTPUT SHOPPING CART");
               shoppingCart.printTotal();
               break;
           // Quit
           case 'q':
               br.close();
               System.exit(0);
               }
           }
       }
    }
     public static void main(String args[]){

   try
   {
       System.out.println("Enter Customer's Name:");
       String customerName = br.readLine();
       System.out.println("Enter Today's Date:");
       String currentDate = br.readLine();
       System.out.println();

       ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart(customerName, 
currentDate);
       System.out.println("Customer Name: " + shoppingCart.getCustomerName());
       System.out.println("Today's Date: " + shoppingCart.getDate());

       printMenu(shoppingCart);
   }
   catch (IOException ioe)
   {
       System.out.println(ioe.toString());
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println(e.toString());
   }
 }
```

}

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It should run in [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/java), for example. After removing undeclared code, what remained worked.

Comment: Hello I have edited it with the entire project code. The problem I am having is when I enter an option that is not given after entering the name and date it's supposed to continue to prompt for a valid choice.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear. See my answer.

Comment: @aaron it does not work as intended. If I input an option that is not listed in the menu it's supposed to prompt for the user to enter another option. This code does that but also shows the entire menu.

Comment: Put the code that displays the "choose an option" prompt and accepts the user's response into its own nested loop which repeats until the user enters a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was quite ambiguous! Anyway.
Put these lines outside the while loop so that they are printed only once.

```
   System.out.println("\nMENU");
   System.out.println("a - Add item to cart");
   System.out.println("d - Remove item from cart");
   System.out.println("c - Change item quantity");
   System.out.println("i - Output items' descriptions");
   System.out.println("o - Output shopping cart");
   System.out.println("q - Quit");
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Choose an option:");
```

Comment: Please get clarity by commenting on the original post.

Comment: Yes it does exit but I need it to continue to prompt for a valid choice when an invalid option is given.

Comment: @Blaze101 can you enter the inputs you are giving here.
for me it doesn't exit but it prompts if I enter an invalid input

Comment: @hsnd The inputs I am using are: Blaze, June 1 2018, f, s, q. When I type f and s it prints the entire menu when its suppose to just prompt for another option

Comment: @hsnsd Thank you very much and I am sorry that my question was ambiguous I am now learning java and I am not sure how to explain things well.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from asker's comment:

> The inputs I am using are: `Blaze`, `June 1 2018`, `f`, `s`, `q`. When I type `f` and `s` it prints the entire menu when its suppose to just prompt for another option

Use a variable to decide whether to print the menu:

```
boolean shouldPrintMenu = true;

while (true) {
    if (shouldPrintMenu) {
        // ...
    } else {
        shouldPrintMenu = true;
    }

    System.out.println("Choose an option:");
    choice = br.readLine().charAt(0);

    if (!( (choice == 'a') || (choice == 'd')
        || (choice == 'c') || (choice == 'i')
        || (choice == 'o') || (choice == 'q')))
    {
        shouldPrintMenu = false;
        continue;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I did this but it still gives the menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for having patience with me. I tried it and it worked although someone else posted an easier solution in the future to make my work look professional I will use it this way.